# How to Restrict Specific Ip Addresses to Xampp

Tags: php, apache, xampp, httpd.conf

In my scenario i have successfully installed xampp. and i have some small websites and web apps. I want to restrict some of network ips to access only the website. I have tried many ways like

```
Order allow,deny
deny from all 
allow from 192.168.1.107
```

also did it with `</Directory /xampp/htdocs/webapp>`. But it didn't work.

When I do this thing. even my computer 192.168.1.107 isn't able to access the website. this is the actual problem occurring.

IN my case my static ip reserved from my router and i want to restrict it to only my ip or the ip give to httpd.conf file.

Comment: Place .htaccess in the root directory.

Answer (score 2):

Use htaccess and allowed access to your ip address only

```
# Remove the php extension from the filename
# Disable directory browsing 
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
# Set the headers for the restful api
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin 192.168.1.107
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET"
#Deny from %{REQUEST_FILENAME}
```

Update

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET"
```

can contain GET,PUT,DELETE,POST

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,PUT,DELETE,POST"
```

Depends on what you want to achieve

Comment: 1. what i want to know is that .htaccess file should be inside of my webapp folder which i want to restrict by ip address ?
2. Can I add multiple ip addresses.
3. My scenario is quite simple. I dont have that much knowledge of GET PUT DELETE POST

Comment: .htaccess should be inside you project root @TheMangoMan

Comment: I tried to put it on htdocs folder after that i am unable to access the webserver it says that permission denied.

Comment: @TheMangoMan add it at the root of your project. Not at the root of your htdocs